# jquery and django - How to validate a video url

Tags: jquery, django, video, youtube, vimeo

I want the people to share videos using the video urls of youtube or vimeo. But before saving it, I want to check whether the video exists or not. I can check whether a given url exists, but how do I validate whether a video exist or not? I would like to that on the client side. Or if not in the `views.py` itself. Any help will be grateful. Thank you!

Comment: You may want to check if there are apis by youtube/vimeo to check status of the video provided the url. If its there you can use it to validate either at client side js or on server.

Answer (score 2):

**Client-side**

```
//here, oHg5SJYRHA0 is YouTube id
$.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/oHg5SJYRHA0',
    success: function() {
        //it exists!
    },
    error: function(jqXhr) {
        if(jqXhr.status == 400) {
            //it doesn't exist
        }
    }
});
```

**Server-side**

Make a `HEAD` request from the `views.py`.
Look at the built-in `urllib`/`urllib2`, or use [`requests`](http://requests.readthedocs.org/):

```
import requests

r = requests.head('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0')
if r.status_code == 404:
    print 'It doesn\'t exist!'
```